# What is the scope of my variable when I use let?

Tags: javascript, variables, window, global

Im new in javascript and in programming.

If I declare a variable with `var` I see that my variable is declared globally and my variable is inside the `window` object.
Example:

```
var element1 = 1;
window.element1; //This returns 1
```

But when I use `let` I can't access my variable using the window object.
Example:

```
let element2 = 1;
window.element2; //This returns undefined
```

So, where has been my variable `element2` been declared?
What is the scope of `element2` ?

Comment: [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) does not create properties of the window object when declared globally (in the top-most scope).

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing scope and automatic attachment to the default object.

If you use `let` **or** `var` outside of any block, function, or module then the scope will be global.

`var` will also attach a property of the same name to the default object (which is `window` in the case of JS running in a browser).